# EXO 2, Helvetica Neue, roboto family i used for UI apps design

Tags: interface-design, font-recommendation

i usually used EXO 2, Helvetica Neue, roboto family  for UI apps design, is it standard for this or and alternatives. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sans serif fonts are mostly used for app UI's. You can find some free ones via [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Sans%20Serif&subset=latin) while Proxima Nova, Helvetica Neue, Avenir Next are some good commercial alternatives.

Comment: thnx... for ur help.